# Accessing a class within a class from another class

Tags: php, oop, class, design-patterns, object

I need my parent classes to be able to access methods within the child classes. Child classes are obviously able to access their inherited parent class methods.

But what if child A wants to borrow a toy that belongs to child B? Child A will ask the parent if it's okay to borrow that toy from child B. The parent tells child A that they will grab it from child B's room and give it to child A to play with.

I have also created this scenario below to help illustrate what I am needing here. Not really sure how to go about doing this.

[STORY]

Let's say you have purchased a new House. You want certain areas of your hours repainted. Oh, and by the way, you need your plumbing looked at.

So we have a Person, House, Painter, & Plumber.

The Person will find the problem areas in the House, and write them down. The Person will then need to find a Plumber and a Painter and call them, reporting their issues.

The Plumber and Painter will then show up to the House with their specialized tools and equipment to carry on with their job.

The **House** will have have these areas:

1. Toilet
2. Sink
3. Shower
4. Exterior Siding
5. Interior Walls

   - The Plumber will need access to the Toilet, Sink, and Shower.
   - The Painter will need access to the Exterior Siding and Interior Walls.

So the Plumber and Painter have arrived at the house to begin doing what they do best.

Firstly, the plumber will need to perform his job inside, so the Painter will begin with painting the Exterior Siding and move to the interior walls, once the Plumber is done.

The Plumber has finished his job. The Plumber reports back to the Person to let them know the job is complete.

The Person then tells the Painter that the Plumber has finished, and that the Painter can begin painting the Interior Walls when the Painter is ready.

Which class structure would be best in this scenario? I read up on a couple patterns that have grabbed my interest.

Command Pattern & Object Pooling.

I'm thinking Object Pooling is more of the route to take. Any input here?

Also, if I did take the Object Pooling route, would it be better to instantiate each class within the constructor and have it ready to be used for later? OR should I instantiate each class only when I need to used it? (probably done via some "run" or "execute" method).

Examples would be appreciated.

Also, I would prefer not using static calls!

Comment: ANOTHER EXAMPLE: Let's say the parent wanted to know what book child_a was reading. `$parent->run('child_a', 'get_book');` which would equate to `$child_a->get_book();`

Comment: where is get_book() defined? in the base class and implemented in the derived? if the method is not defined in the base class, then how can it know about derived class methods?

Comment: `child_a` is instantiated in the parent class automatically. `get_book()` is defined in the subclass: `child_a`. the parent method run just simply says that it needs to execute the `child_a` method `get_book();`

Comment: With all the decription you've dropped here it looks like you have forgotten to clearly formulate a question. Can you add a one/two-sentence question to your "question"? A "Not really sure how to go about doing this." is not a question in my eyes. Stories are fine, but please *ask*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is create a `static` variable in your parent class that holds all the references to your sub-instances (you have to keep track of the instances yourself, for example in your `function __construct` and `function __destruct`.

```
class Parent {
    public static $references = array;

    public function __construct() {
        Parent::$references[] = $this;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        // loop through $references and kill $this from it.
    }

    public function run($ref, $func) {
         // find the reference in $references and store to $r
         if (method_exists($func, $r)) {
             $r->$func();
         }
    }
```